# where to find the history of hive queries executed on Hue?

Tags: hue

where to find the history of hive queries executed on Hue.I couldnt find  any queries saved in beeswax_queryhistory or beeswax_savedquery.

Answer (score 2):

The query is now saved into table `desktop_document2`, not `beeswax_savedquery` anymore.

Search for column `type = 'query-impala'`, and you should be able to find your saved query over there.

My table looks like below:

```sql
MariaDB [hue_513]> select * from desktop_document2 order by id desc limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 id: 50178
           owner_id: 1
               name: Test
        description: Eric's Test query
               uuid: 9cc2006e-9745-43bb-966d-f0bc12da2d2a
               type: query-impala
               data: {"loadingHistory": false..........
              extra:
      last_modified: 2020-01-06 14:33:03
            version: 1
         is_history: 0
parent_directory_id: 1
             search: select * from test.my_table
         is_managed: 0
         is_trashed: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I would add, join to auth_user table to find the user (owner_id)